# Set Private Variable for Reuse In Encapsulated JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, encapsulation

I have a JavaScript function that is reading some data from a text file containing JSON. Ideally, I wanted to pass all the JSON data to a private variable within my encapulated function, so that if I was required to read the data again the variable could be used.

I don't want to be reading the text file everytime I'm need to make certain checks. To me, this doesn't sound good for performance.

Here's my code:

```
function someObj() {
    var siteDataSet = null;

    this.Init = function () {
        populateData();
    }

    this.GetPageData = function () {
        var props = new Array();

        props[0] = siteDataSet.pagetitle;
        props[1] = siteDataSet.week_no;
        props[2] = siteDataSet.intro_text;

        return props;
    }

    function populateData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "data.txt",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "",
            success: function (result) {
                siteDataSet = result;
            },
            error: function () { },
            complete: function () { }
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    o_obj = new someObj();
    o_obj.Init();

    var t = o_obj.GetPageData();
});
```

As you can see, I'm calling `Init()` to use jQuery Ajax to pass all JSON to a variable called `siteDataSet`. When I call `GetPageData()`, the siteDataSet variable is null when this should not be the case.

Am I approaching what I am trying to achieve in a completely absurd way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because your ajax call happens asynchronously and has not yet completed when you attempt to access the variable. Typically, in a situation like that, your best bet is to use a [promise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) which will tell your code to expect a result, since it has not yet been set.

There are several libraries that provide an implementation, such as: https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec

As an alternative, could create a method you wish to be called on completion that will have all of the code you wish to execute and then pass it in. Something like:

```
function afterRetrieved(o_obj) {
  var t = o_obj.GetPageData();
  ...
}

o_obj.Init(afterRetrieved);
```

That passes the function into your `Init` method to be executed after the data is retrieved. It would require a few changes to your implementation as below:

```
this.Init = function (fn) {
    populateData(fn);
 }

function populateData(fn) {
  ....
  success: function (result) {
     siteDataSet = result;
     fn(this)
  },
  ...
}
```

I'd imagine that either of those should resolve your issue.

Comment: You're absolutely correct about the asynchronous ajax call being an issue. I got you solution implemented successfully but then I also noticed that by setting the "async:false" property on my ajax call seemed to solve my issues. Is using "async:false" bad practice compared to your solution?

Comment: It is not bad practice per se, but remember the A in AJAX does stand for asynchronous. The biggest issue is will be performance. By blocking until completion, the script hangs until the remote server completes its processing. Usually the delay is not much of an issue, but large amounts of processing, a slow connection, high load or other factors can make the request take longer than expected. The callback method allows the user to continue using the site while the request is processed. In the end, you will have to make the determination about what the best experience for your users would be.